# LINQ DateTime Formatting of nullable Date Field

Tags: linq

I have the following where I need to get only the Date (not datetime) from ReqDate and RepDeclined which are both nullable datetime fields.

```
var info = from pr in db.Prog        
join tf in db.In_Lens        
on pr.PID equals tf.PID        
select new        
 { ReqDate = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",tf.ReqDate),          
   ReqDeclinedDate = tf.ReqDeclined.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")       
 }).ToList()
```

It is not working as ReqDate and RepDeclined are both nullable datetime fields. I also tried String.Format but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do

```
var info = from pr in db.Prog        
join tf in db.In_Lens        
on pr.PID equals tf.PID        
select new        
{
    ReqDate = (tf.ReqDate == null ? "" : tf.ReqDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")),
    ReqDeclinedDate = (tf.ReqDeclined == null ? "" : tf.ReqDeclined.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
}).ToList()
```

to avoid the NullReferenceException caused by the `.ToString` call on a null object.

**or**

Use `String.Format` in both cases:

```
var info = from pr in db.Prog        
join tf in db.In_Lens        
on pr.PID equals tf.PID        
select new        
{
    ReqDate = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",tf.ReqDate),
    ReqDeclinedDate = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",tf.ReqDeclined)
}).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Had been struggling with this for a while. Found this works for me.

```
var info = (from pr in db.Prog        
            join tf in db.In_Lens        
            on pr.PID equals tf.PID        
            select new { tf.ReqDate, tf.ReqDeclined}).ToList();

var infoFormatted = info.Select(x => new { ReqDate = x.ReqDate.HasValue?x.ReqDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"):"", ReqDeclined = x.ReqDeclined.HasValue?x.ReqDeclined.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"):""});
```